# Problema al escoger un celda con jquery

Tags: php, css, html5, css3

Tengo la siguiente tabla

```js
$('body').on("click",'.modificar', function(){
        selectedRow = $(this).parents('.selecTablerow');
        var codigo_nota = selectedRow.find("td.cod_nota").attr('id');
    alert (codigo_nota);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
            <th id="nombre_Estudiante">#</th>
              <th id="nombre_Estudiante">Estudiante</th>
        <th id="nombre_Actividad">Números Primos y Compuestos,        Criterios de Divisibilidad</th>
        <th id="nombre_Actividad">Magnitudes y Unidades</th>
          <tr>
          </tr>
          <tr class="selecTablerow">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Emilio Agudelo Garrido</td>
            <td class="cod_nota" id="8"><a class="modificar" href="#ventana1" data-toggle="modal">5</a>
            </td>
            <td class="cod_nota" id="9"><a class="modificar" href="#ventana1" data-toggle="modal">4</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
 </body>
```

La idea es que cuando de clic en una nota esta me debe mostrar el código de cada una de ellas 8 y 9 respectivamente, pero solo me esta mostrando el un solo código, no se que mas hacer, se supone que debería buscar por la clase el id, pero no lo esta haciendo como es debido, agradecería mucho la ayuda de ustedes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que está pasando es que el selector que estás usando es una clase, y como hay más de un elemento con la misma clase, solo está tomando el primer elemento. En lugar de seleccionar desde el `.selecTablerow'`, lo que puedes hacer es simplemente llamar al padre de tu elemento `.modificar` y atrapar su ID, de la siguiente manera: `$(this).parent().attr('id');`

Adjunto código:

```js
$('body').on("click",'.modificar', function(){
        var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        alert (id);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
            <th id="nombre_Estudiante">#</th>
              <th id="nombre_Estudiante">Estudiante</th>
        <th id="nombre_Actividad">Números Primos y Compuestos,        Criterios de Divisibilidad</th>
        <th id="nombre_Actividad">Magnitudes y Unidades</th>
          <tr>
          </tr>
          <tr class="selecTablerow">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Emilio Agudelo Garrido</td>
            <td class="cod_nota" id="8"><a class="modificar" href="#ventana1" data-toggle="modal">5</a>
            </td>
            <td class="cod_nota" id="9"><a class="modificar" href="#ventana1" data-toggle="modal">4</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
 </body>
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias, funciono a la primera